# Facebook Graphi API does not list page accounts in offline mode

Tags: facebook-graph-api

My offline Facebook application is trying to retrieve the accounts associated with a specific user id who has previously authorized the application:

https://graph.facebook.com/(userid)/accounts?access_token=(token)

Even though I am passing a valid access token, Facebook returns: 
OAuthException: An access token is required to request this resource.

I verified that my access token is correct by querying the likes connection with the same userid and access token:

https://graph.facebook.com/(userid)/likes?access_token=(token)

For this second statement, Facebook returns the expected result.

My application has manage_pages and offline_access permissions. The access token I am using is the access token Facebook returned when the user authorized the application. I don't understand why it works for the likes connection but not for the accounts connection.

Answer (score 2):

Facebook provides different access tokens, some are shorter and some are longer. Without realizing the difference, I had used the shorter ones, created as type='client_cred'. These work fine for retrieving friends lists, lists of fan pages, publishing to stream etc. but apparently they do not work for getting accounts information.

Here is an example of both types of access tokens. Apparently the first one lacks session information (which is the middle part of the second access token).

> 116122545078207|EyWJJYqrdgQgV1bfueck320z7MM.
>   116122545078207|2.1vGZASUSFMHeMVgQ_9P60Q__.3600.1272535200-500880518|EyWJJYqrdgQgV1bfueck320z7MM.

Answer (score 0):

If your access token is wrong facebook returns this:

```
{
   "error": {
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "message": "Error validating access token."
   }
}
```

It seems that the token is not passed to the graph api. Depending on which SDK you use to pass the token, there are different errors that can occur. The PHP SDK for example ignores the token you pass and tries to get the token from the session cookie, which causes errors. Could you clarify how are you making the graph api calls?

I have verified that with a valid token you can get the accounts data. Have you tried pasting this into your browser https://graph.facebook.com/(userid)/accounts?access_token=(token)?

Comment: Thank you very much. Yes I had tested the problem in the browser. The access token is valid, but does not work. I was not aware that there a different kinds of access tokens, though. The one I was using only worked for likes, friends, publish stream etc. but not for accounts.

Comment: @carina Would you mind sharing the link where you read about the different tokens. I haven't heard of something like that, and am interested in how it works.

Comment: Link is: 
http://benbiddington.wordpress.com/2010/04/23/facebook-graph-api-getting-access-tokens/

Comment: Thank you very much for sharing. I always use user_agent authentication and never had this issue. These bits of knowledge are always useful when dealing with facebook :D